# Salt schedule not executing function

Tags: scheduled-tasks, salt-stack

I have the scheduler enabled on my salt master. I have a job that is configured to execute a runner function on a list of machines every month, like this example:

```
schedule:
  updater:
    args:
    - L@machine1,machine2,machine3
    cron: 0 * * * *
    enabled: true
    function: util.patch_selected
    jid_include: true
    maxrunning: 1
    name: updater
```

I've confirmed that the runner function (including the arguments) works fine on its own, however the scheduler does not execute the runner function. I've run `salt-run saltutil.sync_runner` on the master, and `salt '*' saltutil.refresh_pillar` on all the minions. What am I missing to get this running?

Comment: how is the schedule configured? in a master config file? have you restarted the master? is croniter installed into the python that the master runs as. 

are you getting errors in the master log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `salt-run jobs.last_run target=<minion name>` on the minion helped decipher the issue. It turns out that the "function" portion of a job schedule refers to a runner on the master, which doesn't work when targeting a minion. A workable solution for this was

```
schedule:
  patch_updates:
    args: 
    - salt-call util.patch_selected
    cron: 0 * * * *
    enabled: true
    function: cmd.run
    jid_include: true
    maxrunning: 1
    name: patch_updates
```